# How do i read the eventlog of windows service

Tags: c#, windows, event-log

I am trying to modify an already written Windows service.

I see the source has an System.diagnostic.EventLog object which logs different action of the service.

I am trying to figure out how do i read this log. From semantics it seems that Eventlog  is logging several actions of service.

where is this log stored, how can i see it, i need access to it as my service sometimes stop intermittently.

I tried to google it but did not find any solid answers. Putting the questions simply what is an eventlong and how do i use it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In 'Computer Management' you'll see an entry labelled 'Event Viewer'. Depending on which version of Windows you're running, there will be several sub-entries below this conforming to each of the event logs Windows maintains. Your application will probably be logging to the 'Application' log, although it might also log to 'System'. Click these subitems to have their log contents show up in the central pane.